# how can we give random stream name (in url) for a stream for RTMP and Videocore

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video-capture, rtmp, videocore

I am making app code which is working for RTMP server (Wowza Server) and video core Lib. I am giving RTMP Stream url like below

```
[_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://"andStreamKey:@"Something"];
```

Now I want to give the random values for rtmp stream. 
If I enter a random stream name (in url) for a stream which doesn't exist, it lets me connect and stream. How can I do this? how can get the url from my server that is php then i will play that video on wowza server based on that URL is it possible to send the video while capturing every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
-(NSString *)createRandomURLStreamName
{
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [ [ NSDate date ] timeIntervalSince1970 ];
    NSString *randomURL = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"M%f", timeStamp];
    randomURL = [ randomURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"" ];
    return randomURL ;
}
```

this will be unique everytime as its uses timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for Replay And do you have any idea about uploading video while capturing i know it is possible by avfoundation and uiimage picker but i use vieo core library for broadcast video Thanks for for the random url